# SQL / SSRS - How do I avoid duplicate cells resulting from 2 joins having a different number of results

Tags: sql, reporting-services

All,

I need some help figuring out the following;

We have "requests"
- On these requests, both Shipments & Receipts take place.
- The number of shipments [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrhUn.jpg)and receipts do not always match
- we may ship 1 specific part, and get a different part back
- we may ship 2 parts, and receive 3 parts back, of which only 1 part matched the shipments
- we may ship 3 units, which were 3 different part-id's, and receive 3 units of the same part-id back..

I am trying to create a report that shows me the total number of receipts and total number of shipments per part, in one report.

The issue i am running into is as follow
- If the total number of different PART-ID's doesn't match between shipping and receiving, the report duplicates cells on the item that had less 
i.e.   If there are less Shipped parts than received parts, the shipments duplicate in the rows generated to display the extra received parts..

I have "dumbed down" the code to only show a few relevant fields.
example:

```
RMA ID    Shipped Item  Received items
1202504   V7W8N         0FCDKD
1202504   V7W8N         V7W8N
1222153   0FCDKD        0FCDKD
1222153   V7W8N         0FCDKD
```

In this example.. the 2nd line has the "shipped item" duplicated.  and the 4th line has the "received item" duplicated..  both fields would ideally return NULL

The code:

```
select distinct

request.request_id as [RMA ID]
,shipment_detail.item_id as [Shipped Item]
,rec_detail.item_id as [Received items]

from request
left outer join shipment_detail on shipment_detail.request_id =     request.request_id
left outer join receiving_detail rec_detail on rec_detail.request_id =     request.request_id

where  request.request_id IN ('1202504','1222153')
order by request.request_id
```

How do i get my desired result?  How do i make it so it shows like the follow, so i can sum up quantities appropriately..
Desired result:

```
RMA ID    Shipped Item  Received items
1202504   V7W8N         0FCDKD
1202504   NULL          V7W8N
1222153   0FCDKD        0FCDKD
1222153   V7W8N         NULL
```

I use SSRS to ultimately visualize the reports...   perhaps there are other ways?

Any help or workaround would be appreciated!!

Comment: Without fully understanding your problem... and At first glance shipment_Detail or receiving detail have multiple records for a request_ID.  You could sub select each table to give you the distinct ship_Detail ... change `LEFT OUTER JOIN shipment_detail` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN (Select distinct request_ID, item_ID from shipment_detail) as Shipment_Detail` Applying similar concept to receiving_Detail .  However without understanding why the record is duplicated in these tables this may not serve your purpose. We would need to see data in those two tables for requests in your in to better understand

Answer (score 0):

I am using the windows function ROW_NUMBER() to figure out rows where ShippedItem or ReceivedItem has to be set null. This trick has been very useful for me.

```
select 
    [RMA ID]
    ,CASE WHEN ShippedRowNo = 1 THEN [Shipped Item] ELSE NULL END AS [Shipped Item]
    ,CASE WHEN ReceivedRowNo = 1 THEN [Received items] ELSE NULL AND AS [Received items]
from
    (select distinct
        request.request_id as [RMA ID]
        ,shipment_detail.item_id as [Shipped Item]
        ,rec_detail.item_id as [Received items]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY request.request_id,shipment_detail.item_id ORDER BY rec_detail.item_id) AS ShippedRowNo
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY request.request_id,rec_detail.item_id ORDER BY shipment_detail.item_id) AS ReceivedRowNo
    from request
    left outer join shipment_detail on shipment_detail.request_id =     request.request_id
    left outer join receiving_detail rec_detail on rec_detail.request_id =     request.request_id
    where  request.request_id IN ('1202504','1222153')
) RMA
order by [RMA ID]
```

Comment: So this code actually did seem to work in eliminating the duplicates, which is grand, but we would still (ideally) like to see a sorting improvement. -- The result comes up, with the first line containing 2 different part-id's, even though we do have similar parts being received and shipped...     Is there a way to combine ship & receive parts into one row, if they are the same part Id?   all other functionality seems to be OK now